# Null pointer exception in Class (code seems fine) Java

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

## Problem With NPE that shouldn't be Null at all, Plz help

Hi guys, i have this code which displays an object in a table
the method savet saves the object into that class so it can be referenced, and it works(tried and tested) but when i try to call method displayTeacher i get a null pointer exception. this is because it is not recognizing t1, even though it is clearly in the class,Even as an attribute

```
public class Display
{
    private JTable table;
    private JFrame f;
    private int i = 0;
    public SubjectTeacher t1;

    public void savet (SubjectTeacher teachIn)
    {
        SubjectTeacher tempt = new SubjectTeacher(teachIn.getName(), teachIn.getSurname(), teachIn.getID(), teachIn.getPay(), teachIn.getSubjectID());
        t1 = tempt;
    }
    
    public void displayTeachers()
    {
        f = new JFrame("Teachers");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    
        String[] columnNames =  {"Name", "Surname", "ID", "Pay", "Subject"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {
             t1.getName(),
             t1.getSurname(),
             t1.getID(),
             t1.getPay(),
             t1.getSubjectID()
            }
          };
    JTable table = new JTable (data, columnNames);
    f.add(table);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated since i must finish a school project very soon,
Thanks,Matt

Comment: do you call `public void savet (SubjectTeacher teachIn)` method before? `t1` is `null` until it's assigned to an object.

Comment: Why not just create the SubjectTeacher object in the constructor and assign it to t1 instead of assigning tempt to t1?

Comment: show the flow control of your code ..

Comment: It would really help if you provide information about the location (exact line) where the NPE occurs... Now we have to guess, which makes it much harder to help you out. (Note: a line number does not help, as you example snippet does not have line numbers)

Comment: sorry about that, it comes up on

``    public void displayTeachers()
    {
        f = new JFrame("Teachers");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500,400);
        f.setVisible(true);

        String[] columnNames =  {"Name", "Surname", "ID", "Pay", "Subject"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {
             t1.getName(),
             t1.getSurname(),
             t1.getID(),
             t1.getPay(),
             t1.getSubjectID()
            }
          };``
that part of the code, in the first reference to t1 @Veger

Comment: please add further details (especially code) to the question instead of in a comment - the latter tends to be unreadable :-) Also, consider showing a SSCCE: without, trying to tryk these types of errors are just blind guesses.

Answer (score 2):

> this is because it is not recognizing `t1`, even though it is clearly in the class

It's in the class, but is it ever *initialized*? Reference type fields have a [default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) of `null`, so if you never assign `t1` to anything before trying to call non-static methods on it you will get a `NullPointerException` (since `t1` would be `null`). In your case, the only place you are assigning `t1` is in the `savet` method, so if you don't call this method *before* you call `displayTeachers` `t1` will still be `null`.

Comment: the problem is i have tried it and savet works, i always call savet before displayTeachers, and so t1 will be populated...

Comment: @MatthewCassar Try printing `t1` at the start of `displayTeachers`. Also, is there any other place in the code where you assign `t1`?

Comment: i have done that already
the line
        System.out.println(t1.getName());
works in savet but not when called immediately after in displayTeachers

Answer (score 1):

You said that you call the 2 methods from different classes. Are you sure you call the methods on the same instance of Display? You probably need only one instance of Display, so you should use Singleton Design Pattern, to ensure that there is only one instance.

Another observation is that in you method:

```
        public void savet (SubjectTeacher teachIn)
            {
                SubjectTeacher tempt = new SubjectTeacher(teachIn.getName(), teachIn.getSurname(), teachIn.getID(), teachIn.getPay(), teachIn.getSubjectID());
                t1 = tempt;
            }
```

it would be easier if you write `t1=teachIn`, and would have the same effect.

EDIT:
Your Display class should look something like this:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTable;

    public class Display {
        private static Display instance;
        private JFrame f;
        public SubjectTeacher t1;

        private Display() {
        }

        public static Display getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Display();
            }

            return instance;
        }

        public void savet(SubjectTeacher teachIn) {
            t1 = teachIn;
        }

        public void displayTeachers() {
            f = new JFrame("Teachers");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(500, 400);
            f.setVisible(true);

            String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Surname", "ID", "Pay", "Subject" };
            Object[][] data = { { t1.getName(), t1.getSurname(), t1.getID(),
                    t1.getPay(), t1.getSubjectID() } };

            f.add(new JTable(data, columnNames));
        }
    }
```

When you want to create a new instance of display:
instead of `Display d = new Display();` you should type: `Display d = Display.getInstance();`
This way, there will be only one instance of Display, and you will be referring to the same object in both classes.

Comment: you call the methods on the same instance of Display?

Comment: i cant use the same instance, since they are in 2 different classes
in menu class  d.displayTeachers();
in enter teachers class  dp.savet(subTeach[iT]);

Comment: Well I think there is your problem. You can either make the Display class`s methods and atributes static (all the methods and atributes you call from other classes should be static), and make no instance of the class, and call the methods with Display.method(); and refer the atributes with Display.atribute; Or you can use Singleton Design Pattern.

Comment: this is starting to seem impossible

Answer (score 0):

Is `savet` called from a different thread then `displayTeachers`? If so try replacing `public SubjectTeacher t1;` with `public volatile SubjectTeacher t1;`

Comment: i am calling the 2 methods from different classes, however volatile still doesnt work :/ thans anyway

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling **savet(SubjectTeacher)** method before you call **displayTeachers()**. My guess is that you are calling **displayTeachers()** and the **savet(SubjectTeacher)** has not been called. So `t1` is `null` and you are getting the `NullPointerException` when you try to get the data from `t1`.

Comment: I am calling that, (there is a whole other class for entering a teachers details) and t1, when tested in savet works

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you use the `Display` class in two other classes.

Do you have 2 different instantiations? Or in other terms: do you call `new Display()` in both classes?

If so, are you 100% sure that in **both** classes you call the `savet()` method?

It might be possible that you call `savet()` for one instantiation and `displayTeachers()` for the other instantiation. Which will definitally result in your NPE problem.